# How to install package found in Ubuntu Packages website

Tags: apt, package-management

I need to install a specific version of the kernel. I found the package that I want here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/linux-image-5.0.0-36-generic

But I'm not sure how to update my sources.list to be able to find this package. What pieces of information from that page can I use to know which repository holds this package, and how to form the sources.list line to find it with apt?

Thanks.

Comment: That package is *deprecated* and no longer available; as it contains many *unpatched* issues, and was a HWE kernel from Ubuntu 19.04 which is EOL; it's *unsupported* and no longer available for download via `apt` commands as it'll only give problems. An updated system will not ask for it  (GA kernel for *bionic* is 4.15; with HWE using 5.4 now; no repository contains the *deprecated* package)

Comment: @guiverc I already downloaded it WITH apt. I know it is deprecated... If it is deprecated or not is not the question, you can still download deprecated packages with APT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still exists in 18.04 sources (if you are still using 18.04, 20.04 you would have to manually download them as you could mess up your installation).  Just need to make sure you grab the right parts of it to install.  Normally, it is the headers, image and the modules.

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.0.0-36 linux-headers-5.0.0-36-generic linux-image-5.0.0-36-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-36-generic
```